# vscode error on "end" parameter of print function in python

Tags: python, printing, visual-studio-code

vscode IDE show me an error on using { print(i,end=' ') } with python language

I have used pycharm IDE and it works correctly ...

```
def showDivisor(number):
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            print(i, end=' ')

showDivisor(24)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GDx9.png)

Comment: You are running on Python 2.

Comment: I use python 3,you can see that in the first line of terminal output on the picture attached

Comment: Nothing in that line indicates a specific Python version. The Syntax error on the other hand is typical for running code with a Python 3 `print()` function on Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Running your code in Python 3.6.5 => no problems.

Running with Python 2.7.13 => the given syntax error.

Click in the lower left in the status line on the **Python** word and select <kbd>Python 3.x</kbd>

You can check which python interpreter is used by looking in the settings of the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing your code via the Code Runner extension, not the Python extension, and so the selected interpreter for the latter is not informing the former. Either use the Python extension to run your code via `Run Python File in Terminal` or you need to configure the Code Runner extension to use Python 3.